# I'm having trouble with macros in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I am having trouble with a macro I recorded in excel.

What I want it to do is

1. start where my selection is and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> to select all of the stuff in the row.
2. I then want to copy it to a new sheet.

I can move from my current sheet (First) to my newest sheet by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd> but then to use this i still have to create a new sheet, move back to my main sheet, and select my start cell. Any suggestions on speeding this up or getting it to move the row I have highlighted instead of the second row.

Comment: `Any suggestions on speeding this up?` Do you have any code to show?

Comment: Code? I just hit the record macro button and then did it once. Everytime I try to run it, it always moves the second row, I need it to move the row I'm in rigght then

Comment: Press ALT+F11 to see the code generated by the macro recorder. If you can't see it at first, look in the modules folder in the top left panel. Edit your question to include the code (copy and paste it into your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have two problems: making the new sheet through the keyboard (so that it can be part of the macro) and also copying the row you're in rather than the second row.

to solve problem 1 you just need a keyboard shortcut, I like this one: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> it creates a new sheet and you are on that sheet after you finish the key combo.

to solve problem 2 you need to re-record record the macro with "relative references" enabled. This apparently was off when you recorded the first time. That's probably why it is copying row 2 instead of the row you're on. To show this go to the developer tab and click the buttton shown in my picture. 
[image: Relative References]

---

So, you need to re-record (with relative references checked!)

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>
- then copy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>)
- then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to create a new sheet. You will start in A1. If you want it to post to the first row, you're set; paste If you want a different row, just incorporate a few down arrows till you're at the correct row.